# Does Column Order Matter in a Group By Clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning how to use GROUP BY clauses with Oracle Database 12c SQL. 
I am wondering if the order in which you list columns in a GROUP BY clause has an effect on the final result when you need to list multiple columns in the clause.

To demonstrate what I mean, I will be using this sample table, BOOKSHELF:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TITLE                                                                                                PUBLISHER            CATEGORY_NAME        RATING  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------  |
| To Kill A Mockingbird                                                                                Harper Collins       ADULTFIC             5       |
| Wonderful Life                                                                                       W.W. Norton          ADULTNF              5       |
| Innumeracy                                                                                           Vintage Books        ADULTNF              4       |
| Kierkegaard Anthology                                                                                Princeton Univ Pr    ADULTREF             3       |
| Anne Of Green Gables                                                                                 Grammercy            CHILDRENFIC          3       |
| Good Dog, Carl                                                                                       Little Simon         CHILDRENPIC          1       |
| Letters And Papers From Prison                                                                       Scribner             ADULTNF              4       |
| The Discoverers                                                                                      Random House         ADULTNF              4       |
| The Mismeasure Of Man                                                                                W.W. Norton          ADULTNF              5       |
| Either/Or                                                                                            Penguin              ADULTREF             3       |
| Polar Express                                                                                        Houghton Mifflin     CHILDRENPIC          1       |
| Runaway Bunny                                                                                        Harper Festival      CHILDRENPIC          1       |
| My Ledger                                                                                            Bryla Press          ADULTNF              5       |
| Complete Poems Of John Keats                                                                         Viking               ADULTREF             2       |
| Under The Eye Of The Clock                                                                           Arcade Pub           CHILDRENNF           3       |
| John Adams                                                                                           Simon Schuster       ADULTNF              4       |
| Truman                                                                                               Simon Schuster       ADULTNF              4       |
| Journals Of Lewis And Clark                                                                          Mariner              ADULTNF              4       |
| Gospel                                                                                               Picador              ADULTFIC             4       |
| Emma Who Saved My Life                                                                               St Martin'S Press    ADULTFIC             3       |
| Midnight Magic                                                                                       Scholastic           CHILDRENFIC          1       |
| Harry Potter And The Goblet Of Fire                                                                  Scholastic           CHILDRENFIC          4       |
| Shoeless Joe                                                                                         Mariner              ADULTFIC             3       |
| Box Socials                                                                                          Ballantine           ADULTFIC             3       |
| Trumpet Of The Swan                                                                                  Harper Collins       CHILDRENFIC          3       |
| Charlotte's Web                                                                                      Harper Trophy        CHILDRENFIC          3       |
| West With The Night                                                                                  North Point Press    ADULTNF              3       |
| The Good Book                                                                                        Bard                 ADULTREF             4       |
| Preaching To Head And Heart                                                                          Abingdon Press       ADULTREF             4       |
| The Cost Of Discipleship                                                                             Touchstone           ADULTREF             3       |
| The Shipping News                                                                                    Simon Schuster       ADULTFIC             4       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The following is a query featuring a GROUP BY clause and its result:

```
select publisher, category_name, avg(rating)
from bookshelf
group by category_name, publisher;

PUBLISHER            CATEGORY_NAME        AVG(RATING)
-------------------- -------------------- -----------
Arcade Pub           CHILDRENNF                     3 
Simon Schuster       ADULTNF                        4 
Mariner              ADULTFIC                       3 
Harper Trophy        CHILDRENFIC                    3 
Harper Festival      CHILDRENPIC                    1 
Viking               ADULTREF                       2 
Mariner              ADULTNF                        4 
Houghton Mifflin     CHILDRENPIC                    1 
Scholastic           CHILDRENFIC                  2.5 
Abingdon Press       ADULTREF                       4 
Princeton Univ Pr    ADULTREF                       3 
Random House         ADULTNF                        4 
North Point Press    ADULTNF                        3 
W.W. Norton          ADULTNF                        5 
Vintage Books        ADULTNF                        4 
Grammercy            CHILDRENFIC                    3 
Penguin              ADULTREF                       3 
Picador              ADULTFIC                       4 
Ballantine           ADULTFIC                       3 
Touchstone           ADULTREF                       3 
Harper Collins       ADULTFIC                       5 
Little Simon         CHILDRENPIC                    1 
Scribner             ADULTNF                        4 
Bryla Press          ADULTNF                        5 
St Martin'S Press    ADULTFIC                       3 
Harper Collins       CHILDRENFIC                    3 
Bard                 ADULTREF                       4 
Simon Schuster       ADULTFIC                       4
```

The following is the same query, but the order in which the columns are listed in the GROUP BY clause is switched:

```
select publisher, category_name, avg(rating)
from bookshelf
group by publisher, category_name;

PUBLISHER            CATEGORY_NAME        AVG(RATING)
-------------------- -------------------- -----------
Simon Schuster       ADULTNF                        4 
Harper Trophy        CHILDRENFIC                    3 
Bard                 ADULTREF                       4 
Harper Festival      CHILDRENPIC                    1 
North Point Press    ADULTNF                        3 
Princeton Univ Pr    ADULTREF                       3 
Scribner             ADULTNF                        4 
Bryla Press          ADULTNF                        5 
Abingdon Press       ADULTREF                       4 
Simon Schuster       ADULTFIC                       4 
Grammercy            CHILDRENFIC                    3 
Random House         ADULTNF                        4 
Picador              ADULTFIC                       4 
Harper Collins       ADULTFIC                       5 
W.W. Norton          ADULTNF                        5 
Vintage Books        ADULTNF                        4 
Little Simon         CHILDRENPIC                    1 
Harper Collins       CHILDRENFIC                    3 
Houghton Mifflin     CHILDRENPIC                    1 
Arcade Pub           CHILDRENNF                     3 
Mariner              ADULTNF                        4 
St Martin'S Press    ADULTFIC                       3 
Scholastic           CHILDRENFIC                  2.5 
Mariner              ADULTFIC                       3 
Ballantine           ADULTFIC                       3 
Penguin              ADULTREF                       3 
Touchstone           ADULTREF                       3 
Viking               ADULTREF                       2
```

Besides the the results being presented in a different order, the results are identical. Is this always the case in this type of scenario?

Comment: you should include an `order by` clause. without that, each time you run the query you get arbitrarily ordered results which may match sometimes, but not always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Order of column names in `GROUP BY` does not matter, results will be the same

NOTE: Result is UN-ordered SET of rows, it means that every time your query is executed - database could potentially return it in different order

- To introduce order into this SET, you need to use `ORDER BY` and order of columns in `ORDER BY` makes difference to order of rows, but not to actual result set